# Identification of embroidery font

Tags: fonts, dst-embroidery

Can you tell me what embroidery font this is?:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: When you finally stab this white whale be sure to stab with your whole body and not just your arms. That way you can keep attached.

Comment: @Tatarize...you lost me at the stabbing....still trying to decipher your comment.  I am curious...can you extrapolate...because it is a Moby?....Well, it was worth a shot!

Comment: "From hell's heart I stab at thee"

Comment: I looked for a while, checked `whatthefont` etc, I couldn't find it. Needle in a haystack sort of question and probably not really for SO.